# Did too many programmers migrate to programmers SE?

Tags: discussion

I'm afraid that SO could become a lonely place. Wasn't there a discussion about failing by competing for the same heads?

Comment: I'm not sure why this was down voted so many times. If the people that down voted could explain why, it might help others construct better questions in the future. His question seems legit even if the answer is "obvious".

Comment: @Andrew Finnell: Welcome to Meta.SO. The downvotes here are somewhat different from the rest of the SE network - they could simply mean "disagree","not a real concern" or (in the case of feature requests) "not needed".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since, according to [Alexa](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackoverflow.com), StackOverflow has over 30 times the traffic and number of visitors, I would guess the answer to be "no".

Comment: You can also use the API ( [SO](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/stats), [PSE](http://api.programmers.stackexchange.com/1.0/stats) ); 562595.71 SO views/day vs. 9819.27 PSE views/day

Answer (score 11):

Uhm...no?

Stack Overflow is a better place for the reduced level of fluff. If fluff is what you came for then, by all means, go *to* Programmers. We'll all be happier that way.

Answer (score 9):

No. Not enough of them have done so.

Answer (score 8):

Only for single core developers. Multicore developers know how to multitask and can be at several sites and have some work done at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't worry, both sites have different goals (and personally, I still follow both :-)